# Why couldn't the internal energy depend upon all the three state variables at the same time?

Tags: thermodynamics

> Does the temperature T change during a free expansion? Suppose it does
>   change, while the internal energy stays the same. In that case we have
>   to conclude that the internal energy depends on both T and the volume
>   V or on both T and the pressure p, but certainly not on T alone.

This is a text from University physics about ideal gases. My confusion as silly as it sounds is, why didn't the author/s write

> "In that case we have to conclude that the internal energy depends on
>   T, P and the volume V. "

Couldn't the internal energy depend upon all the three state variables at the same time if all the three are supposed to change? If not, why is that?

Comment: Might it be due to the fact that $PV$ is a state function?

Comment: Could you please provide some more details about why that's the reason ? I couldn't quiet catch it.

Comment: The equation of state for a material determines the relationship between pressure, volume, and temperature at thermodynamic equilibrium.  So any two of these parameters determine the third parameter.

Comment: @Chet Miller, you comment absolutely resolves that. I'd the same doubt. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, because the fundamental assumption of ‘ideal’ gases is that the internal molecules don’t interact with each other.

Van der Waals gases/molecules (and other forms of matter) have internal interactions, and those interactions do, in general, depend on how tightly packed the molecules or atoms are — something that depends on the volume. By contrast, if we make the assumption that none of those interactions matter, we can state that the internal energy is a function of temperature only

In real gases,contrary to what you would have expected (changing due to all three thermodynamic parameters).It only depends on any of the two functions
The reason for this is that ideal gases follow  Wander wall's equation.The equation is :

$$(P_{real}+\frac{an^2}{V^2})(V-nb)=nRT.$$

From this equation,you can conclude that any one parameter will be a function of other for eg  V is a function of T and P and hence the internal energy depends on only two parameters instead of three

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. While it is true that in a non-ideal gas the internal energy is not simply a function of temperature, it is not true that it is simultaneously a function of $T$,$V$ and $P$. The non-ideal gas still only has 2 independent degrees of freedom (at fixed particle number) and so one parameter will always be a function of the other 2.

Comment: @BySymmetry I think you should post your own answer because it fully addresses the question